# Going to Greece first week in November; can I still see some islands?

Tags: greece, islands

I'll be in Greece the first week in November, for 6 days. Unfortunately I can't go sooner.

I'd really like to see some islands. Is this still possible that time of year without it being overly expensive (compared to other times of year)?

Which islands would it make sense to see (I've read online some ferry routes may be closed in November)?

Comment: When I look at the title I guess they will sink soon

Comment: In general, November will be cheaper than say peak periods such as July and August.  I've been there in October and although the weather is warm, the water is very cold.  I imagine November will be much cooler.

Comment: Why would November be expensive?

Answer (score 7):

I think going anywhere in Greece right now is going to very cheap (relatively) because of the economic/political situation.

The islands that make sense to see depend on where in Greece you are going. If you are say, flying into Athens, Mykonos/Delos is a close ferry away and are well worth seeing if you like ruins. From there you can ferry to Santorini if you like relaxing (or volcanoes).

You should be careful of the economic situation there. If you have a Greek bank card, you will be limited to 60 euro withdrawal limits. Even if you don't have a Greek bank card, in some locations there are reports of ATMs running out of cash. Thus, it might be safe to take a large portion of the money you expect to spend in cash with you ahead of time. Additionally, some smaller businesses are not taking credit cards at this time.

(As several people have commented, the economic and political situation in Greece should change drastically between now and November. My answer is based on the situation as of today.)

Comment: The withdrawal limits are only for cards issued by Greek banks.  Cards issued by foreign banks are not affected.  Please edit.

Comment: Tourists can withdraw up to 600 euros, the same limit it has always been.

Comment: Will it be worth seeing these islands even in November?

Comment: Greece is farther south than most of Europe. It's not going to be as warm as summer, but overall it shouldn't be too bad. Do you care about the sights or the weather more... up to you

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Do you think I could see plenty of good sights still and get around via ferries/whatever between islands in November? I also wonder if hostels/hotels may be closed then.

Comment: @ChadJohnson the average temperature for Athens in November is 15c, so I can't imagine too many things closing. I am sure there will be plenty of hotels/hostels open during that time.

Comment: I guess several hotels and restaurants on the islands will be closed, also you might have trouble finding ferries to certain islands, but people live on them year-round so something is surely available ferry and restaurant wise, you just have to adapt. 
Just be prepared to having bad weather too. 
My suggestion is to seek more traditional hotel accomodation (off season it's cheaper anyway) instead of vacation houses and such as if the weather is bad, you might end up in a musty place with no heating except a single-room AC unit on reverse.

Comment: Greece is still pretty far east, its winters are a lot colder than winters in the southwest of Europe like the coast of southern Spain.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, accommodation during November for Greek islands is going to be cheaper than the rest of the year. Also, flights to islands from mainland Greece are going to be cheaper (especially if you book in advance). The issue will be that only major hotels will be open rather than smaller family businesses/apartments.

So for flights, try [Aegean Air](http://en.aegeanair.com/special-offers/low-fare-calendar/), Ryanair, [Astra Airlines](http://www.astra-airlines.gr/) or [Sky Express](http://www.skyexpress.gr/en-us/destinations/scheduledflights.aspx). I found return flights to Corfu and Chania for less than €100 during November. I would not suggest going to small islands as hotels might be closed. Try what other options these airlines give during November, because ferries are scarce during November and not worth the trouble / price difference.

Comment: Do you think hotels and ferries to/on Santorini and Crete will be accessible at that time of year?

Comment: For Crete 100% sure - both hotels and ferries. For Santorini ferries probably stop around October time, but main hotels will still be open during November.